# Tabbing in Python?

Tags: python

I need to write data to a textfile as a table. Sort of like a database. The header has Drivers, Cars, Teams, Grids, Fastest Lap, Race Time and Points. When I try to write the data that goes under it the don't line up. As some drivers names are longer than others.

It looks a bit like this:

```
|     Driver      |
|Sebastian William|
|Tom Hamilton  |
```

Only 2 of the names actually align with the header. I am only trying to solve the issue with Drivers for now once I figure that out I should be able to gets all the other headers lined up.

Using a for loop through the array of dictionaries I set x to equal the len of the drivers name and 22 is the length of the longest name(18) plus a few spaces.

```
TextFile.write((items['Driver']+'\t|').expandtabs(22-x))
```

Any way of making them line up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [format string syntax](http://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings):

```
>>> "|{:22}|".format("Niki Lauda")
'|Niki Lauda            |'
```

You can also change the alignment:

```
>>> "|{:>22}|".format("Niki Lauda")
'|            Niki Lauda|'
>>> "|{:^22}|".format("Niki Lauda")
'|      Niki Lauda      |'
```

and if you want more flexibility with your column size, you can parametrize that as well:

```
>>> "|{:^{}}|".format("Niki Lauda", 24)
'|       Niki Lauda       |'
```

Comment: I didn't know you could nest fields. It could get confusing with longer format strings. I think I would use field names in that case.

Comment: Field nesting is mentioned at the end of [the Format String Syntax documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) and at the end of [the examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-examples).

Answer (score 2):

On top of the answer provided by Tim, you could opt to use [Tabulate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate) which is very easy to use and customise.

```
table = [["spam",42],["eggs",451],["bacon",0]]
headers = ["item", "qty"]
print tabulate(table, headers, tablefmt="grid")

+--------+-------+
| item   |   qty |
+========+=======+
| spam   |    42 |
+--------+-------+
| eggs   |   451 |
+--------+-------+
| bacon  |     0 |
+--------+-------+
```

This provides support for multiple different database styles too. I prefer this to simply using format because it allows me to completely change the output style by configuring the `tablefmt` argument.